# ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(geometry) does not exist?

Tags: postgis

Not make sense, the [function exists since v2.2](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ApproximateMedialAxis.html),

```sql
SELECT distinct geometrytype(geom) from t; --  POLYGON
SELECT ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(geom) from t;
-- ERROR:  function st_approximatemedialaxis(geometry) does not exist
-- LINE 1: select ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(geom) from t...
```

---

- `select PostGIS_Version()` =  "3.0 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1"
- `select select postgis_full_version()` = *POSTGIS="3.0.1 ec2a9aa" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="120" GEOS="3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 " PROJ="6.3.1" LIBXML="2.9.10" LIBJSON="0.13.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3" WAGYU="0.4.3 (Internal)*
- `select Version()` = "PostgreSQL 12.3 (Ubuntu 12.3-1.pgdg20.04+1) ... 64-bit"
- `\df st_area`, and all other are there...
- `\df public.ST_ApproximateMedialAxis` = no function!

This last check shows that was not installed (!)... Well, the guide say *"This method needs SFCGAL backend"*, how to check it?

Comment: it should be there..  maybe it's a path issue? try `\df public.ST_ApproximateMedialAxis`

Comment: Thanks @JGH, I edited.

Comment: you can check using `select postgis_full_version();` Mine indeed contains `SFCGAL="1.3.2"`

Comment: Thanks @JGH, now we have the cause of the problem (!). Next step, *"how to install SFCGAL?"*

Answer (score 4):

Seems so simple

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_sfcgal;
\df public.ST_ApproximateMedialAxis
```

```
                                 List of functions
 Schema |           Name           | Result data type | Argument data types | Type
--------+--------------------------+------------------+---------------------+------
 public | st_approximatemedialaxis | geometry         | geometry            | func
```

Thanks to @JGH and  https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/179618/7505

Now `postgis_full_version()` shows also SFCGAL version, `SFCGAL="1.3.7"`.